# R: Replacing NAs with the mean value according to secondary column

Tags: r

I can't get out of this:

Let's say I have

```
X   Z
2   1
NA  1
3   1
4   2
NA  2
2   2
30  3
30  3
NA  3
30  3
```

I want to replace the NAs in column X with the mean of the X value for the Xs that have the same value of Z. So I would get

```
X   Z
2   1
2.5 1
3   1
4   2
3   2
2   2
30  3
30  3
30  3
30  3
```

Because mean of X for Z=1 is 2.5,mean of X for Z=2 is 3 and mean of X for Z=3 is 30.

I'm sure there should be an easy way to do this :)

Thanks!
Luis.

Comment: Clue: `aggregate(X ~ Y, FUN=mean, data=DF)`.

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` and `ave` will do it:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  X=c(2, NA, 3, 4, NA, 2, 30, 30, NA, 30),
  Z=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
)

dat$X <- with(dat,ifelse(
  is.na(X),
  ave(X,Z,FUN=function(x) mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)),
  X
))


dat
#      X Z
#1   2.0 1
#2   2.5 1
#3   3.0 1
#4   4.0 2
#5   3.0 2
#6   2.0 2
#7  30.0 3
#8  30.0 3
#9  30.0 3
#10 30.0 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it:

```
my.data <- read.table(text='

 X   Z
 2   1
 NA  1
 3   1
 4   2
 NA  2
 2   2
 30  3
 30  3
 NA  3
 30  3

', header = TRUE, na.strings = "NA")

my.data

my.means <- tapply(my.data$X, my.data$Z, function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))

my.data$X <- ifelse(is.na(my.data$X), my.means[my.data$Z], my.data$X)

      X Z
1   2.0 1
2   2.5 1
3   3.0 1
4   4.0 2
5   3.0 2
6   2.0 2
7  30.0 3
8  30.0 3
9  30.0 3
10 30.0 3
```